# C/C++ encrypt/decrypt with public key

Tags: c++, c, encryption-asymmetric

I'm looking for two functions conceptually similar to these:

```
// returns the encrypted text
string encrypt( string public_key, string pass_phrase, string text );
// returns the original text
string decrypt( string private_key, string pass_phrase, string encrypted_text );
```

where `string` could be a `char*`, a `std::string` or something easily convertible to those two. And where `public_key` and `private_key` can be basically anything, from keys generated with some commands (gpg/ssl stuff or whatever), to keys generated with other **simple** functions.

I've looked into a few cryptography libraries (libgcrypt, libgpgme, openssl ...), but it doesn't look easy at all to implement such functions with those libraries: they require a non-superficial knowledge about asymmetric encryption and a lot of code.

Anyway this task doesn't seem uncommon.
How can I implement the two functions above?

Comment: Have you checked out Keyczar? http://code.google.com/p/keyczar/

Comment: encrypted_text is probably binary data. You need to watch out for embedded zeros. I'd include lengths in the prototypes ...

Comment: @pmg: I realize there's a [c]-tag, but I suppose peoro is thinking of C++'s `std::string`, which is 8-bit clean and includes a length, separate from the contents of the string.

Comment: @pmg: I considered `string` to have a length embedded somewhere. Of course if strings are `char*`s, all of those parameters will need another one for the length: also keys (and potentially even plaint text) are binary.

Comment: @kotlinski: no, I didn't check it out. I'll give it a look!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, encryption *always* requires a non-superficial knowledge of the algorithms involved. It is hard to get right. The "Handbook of Applied Cryptography" is a relatively readable guide to the various algorithms available so it's probably worth a look.

You could also try [cryptlib](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/cryptlib/). It seems to have a well-layered design that gives you sensible defaults for a lot of parameters so you can hopefully get started without having to worry too much about the details.

Comment: Well, I don't agree that much. The two functions of which I gave the signature (plus another one to gen a public/private key pair) should be enough to play with encryption. Of course they aren't very customizable, so they won't be secure enough to be used with something serious, but I guess they're OK for 99% of cases...

Comment: I'll give a look to cryptlib, anyway, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I'd suggest you also change your function signatures to work in terms of bytes, not strings. Crypto generally works on opaque byte arrays and adding string semantics will just make things harder. At this layer, a key is just a set of bytes, a passphrase is a set of bytes, and the clear/cipher text are both sets of bytes. They *may* represent strings with some kind of character encoding (ASCII, UTF-8 or whatever), but the crypto layer doesn't care about that.

Comment: Absolutely disagree.

Answer (score 5):

When someone asks for easy encryption, I can only recommend [KeyCzar](https://github.com/google/keyczar).

It not only provides a clean interface in several languages (that can use the same keys) but also mechanisms to handle key rotations and the like.

And of course, safe defaults for the algorithms implemented so that you don't have to worry about the technical details.

Really, the better easy & safe combination I've seen so far.

Comment: isn't keyczar just a wrapper around openssl etc.?

Comment: @BjornWesen: yes, it is. From the link *Keyczar is designed to be open, extensible, and cross-platform compatible. It is not intended to replace existing cryptographic libraries like OpenSSL, PyCrypto, or the Java JCE, and **in fact is built on these libraries**.* (emphasis mine) The one benefit of KeyCzar is that it chooses safe defaults for you so you do not shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: yeah, and that is of course a very appreciated goal :) I did just find myself in the same situation needing a lightweight library doing some public key sign/verification though, and the thought of having to involve openssl "just" to do that is heavy.. i did find libtom afterwards which is probably ok for many things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don’t need something platform agnostic, Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is a relatively new cryptography API on Windows and is surprisingly intuitive and easy to use. I wrote an article that includes examples of all the main cryptographic operations you’re likely to need in typical applications. The sample code for the article also provides a complete working example for these operations using the Visual C++ compiler.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163389.aspx

To treat public and private keys as strings you could simply use Base64 or a similar encoding.

Comment: The link just gives an index of magazines. Which one has your article? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly those older articles have been archived as chm files. http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJuly2007en-us.chm